# How does thrift work internally?

Tags: thrift

> It combines a software stack with a
>   code generation engine to build
>   services that work efficiently and
>   seamlessly ...

Anyone knows how it works actually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's open source...
I suggest you start here: http://thrift.apache.org/

you can also read the white paper from that site, good luck

Answer (score 0):

Thrift use a IDL language to describe the RPC functions.
See [official site](http://thrift.apache.org/)

About the thrift IDL's syntax:
See [MissingGuide](http://diwakergupta.github.io/thrift-missing-guide/)

the Missing Guide maybe about the earlier version of thrift.
Usually, Thrift user just gen the auto-generated code of RPC, then change the server's code. Client side programming was just like use a in-process library, and you should care the Thrift exception/error in this situation.

Thrift make cross-language/process programming so easy. Enjoy it.

Answer (score 0):

Thrift can be recognized as an Interface Definition Language (IDL) and a higher level of RPC framework as it **internally uses RPC calls to do the client server communication. The required RPC client stubs and  server skeletons are generated for marshalling and unmarshalling by Thrift for this communication.** You only want to worry about writing the Server application, Client Application and the Server implementation which implements the methods of Interfaces inside the generated files.